# Create a custom column( hyperlink type) in sharepoint 2010 using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I want to create a custom column in Sharepoint 2010 using VS 2010. When user click on this hyperlink it should open in modal popup. Please guide me. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 4):

Declare the field as below

```
<Field Type="URL" Format="Hyperlink" Name="MyLinkName" ID="{GUID}" DisplayName="MyLinkDisplayName" Required="TRUE" Group="Custom Columns" />
```

Set 'Type' as "URL" and 'Format' to "Hyperlink" .

*Generate a GUID from VS and add it to the ID attribute. (I removed my GUID)
How to generate a GUID - [Click Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2011/11/03/create-a-list-definition-in-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about modal popups. According to what I read, its a javascript.
So in the field definition you can add the javascript to the "NavigationUrl" attribute as below.

```
NavigateUrl="javascript:alert('Hello')"
```

Not sure whether it solved your problem...